# how to set id of an element using PHP dom?

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I want to set id of an element. I'm using php dom. I could not understand how following will work.

```
DOMElement::setIdAttribute  ( string $name  , bool $isId  )
```

The only description I found for this in manual is -
**Declares the attribute name to be of type ID.**

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add an id attribute to your html element so that it looks like `<p id="frob">...` you dont use `setIdAttribute()` - it declares that the attribute `$name` can be used as an unique identifier for that element - as an alternative/addition of the `id` attribute. Use `setAttribute()` like so:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<html><body><p>FROB</p></body></html>');
$dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->setAttribute('id', 'XXX');
print $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 4):

use for example:

```
DOMElement->setIdAttribute  ('myid', true  );
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `DOMElement::setAttribute`? You could just `setAttribute('id', 'your_id')`, or am I missing something? After that, you could use `setIdAttribute('id', TRUE)` to mark it as the ID.